# CSS display: table-row set height

Tags: html, css, height

I would like to set a specific height in a percentage value. But the display: table-cell doesn't want to set any height.

HTML:

```
    <div id="navigation">
        <div class="title">Titel</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation{
    display: table;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 6%;
    background-color: silver;
}
.title{
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    background-color: lime;
}
#navigation ul li{
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
}
#navigation ul li a{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    background-color: olive;
}
```

For further information please have a look at my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hc5cm620/)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parent (`ul`) of the table rows (`li`) is not a table and does not get a height for itself.

Currently, you have:

```
#navigation ul {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}
```

To get what you want you can try this:

```
#navigation ul {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Remove the `.title` css `width:100%` and use only `height` 
try it

Comment: please remove all tag width and refresh it

Comment: This will change nothing. See my updated [JSFIDDLE URL](http://jsfiddle.net/hc5cm620/1/)

Comment: please put new class for specific row and put it height

Comment: @SakthiKarthik It does not seem like you tried the code provided in the original question but are trying different things to see what works. It would be more useful if you provided tested code so the OP can compare and use something that works